# Copy values and formatting to another Google spreadsheet with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a sheet built that's pulling in data from an XML feed. I have a script written that will then break out that one sheet into several other sheets based on the contents of a particular column.  This all works fine.

My problem is that after I pull in the data from XML and before I split it into new sheets, I add some columns, do some formatting, etc. And then when I copy a row (using appendRow()) to the new sheet, I lose the formatting and formulas.

The code I'm using currently Is:

```
var datarange = template_sheet.getDataRange();

for (var i in dataRange) {
   workbook.getSheetByName(dataRange[i][6]).appendRow(dataRange[i]);

}
```

Is there a way to do what I'm looking for? Or do I need to breakout the original data into separate sheets first, then loop through each sheet and do the formatting/formulas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should use the method **copyTo(range, optAdvancedArgs)** of the Range object.

```
var datarange = template_sheet.getDataRange();
for (var i in datarange)
  datarange[i].copyTo(
    workbook.getSheetByName(dataRange[i][6]).getRange(
      workbook.getSheetByName(dataRange[i][6]).getMaxRows()+1, 1));
```

should do the trick

in more legible:

```
var datarange = template_sheet.getDataRange();
for (var i in datarange) {
  var sheet = workbook.getSheetByName(dataRange[i][6].getValue());
  datarange[i].copyTo(sheet.getRange(sheet.getMaxRows()+1, 1));
}
```

Comment: Ya, the only problem with that solution is that I need to loop through each row to find the value of column 6, to copy it to the proper Sheet. Or are you saying that copyTo works exactly the same as appendTo, only it copies formating and formulas as well?

Comment: Well, you can't avoid looping through each row if each individual row potentially goes to a different sheet - your snippet is doing that as well ;-) I added more legible version of the script. Have a look on [link](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_range#copyTo) as copyTo does something different from appendRow. You need to find the first free row with getMaxRows(). @nathangiesbrecht

Answer (score 1):

Copy a tab with values and formatting from one tab to a new tab:

```
function copyTab() {
  var ss, sourceSheet, sourceData, sourceDataRange, newSheetTab;

  ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();//Get active spreadsheet

  sourceSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1");//Get the source sheet tab
  newSheetTab = ss.insertSheet("New Sheet");//Create a new sheet tab

  sourceDataRange = sourceSheet.getDataRange();

  sourceDataRange.copyTo(newSheetTab.getRange(1, 1));//Copies the data from a range of 
  //cells to another range of cells. By default both the values and formatting are copied

}
```